# pdfgrep: how to install pdfgrep on Mac

Tags: macos, pdf, terminal, installation

I am trying to make a `regex search` on a `pdf file` on `Mac`.
For that, I'm trying to install [pdfgrep](https://github.com/Feh/pdfgrep). I have cloned the repository,  but I'm not sure how to install it.

On the `README`, it says to

> use the standard procedure:
>
> ```
> ./configure
> make
> sudo make install
> ```

,but just running these commands doesn't make the installation.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `brew install pdfgrep` or install macports and run `port install pdfgrep`

Comment: running `brew install pdfgrep` worked for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

[running `brew install pdfgrep`](http://macappstore.org/pdfgrep/) worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the regular expression (PCRE) option, please use `brew install pdfgrep --with-pcre`. Or `brew reinstall pdfgrep --with-pcre` if you already installed pdfgrep.

Comment: It seems to not work anymore. I'm using Macos Monterey

Comment: @Kfcaio I tested on pdfgrep version 2.1.2. It already supports PCRE. Just key in `brew install pdfgrep`. The `--with-pcre` option became not necessary.